# Any good example or suggestions to transport image to ROS in Android-JNI?

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs#image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know there's only have a C++ usage for transport image-messages to ROS in official API, and I want to do this in Android. So maybe the [android_camera_driver](https://github.com/ros-android/android_camera_driver) is a good way to achieve this, however, for my target it's too complicated. I just need to transport the image from SD card or any other sources to ROS, never need a camera should open and take a photo or an OpenCV package to import. Only decoding the local image into byte-buffer and transform it to seneor_msgs.CompressedImage messages, and transport it. Therefore, I think the JNI should be a possible way to solve my problem. I'm new to jni and ros, I need some good suggestions to help me built a possible framework based on this structure. Or just tell me my idea is hard to make true, or it's a bad idea!  Thanks in advance! Any good suggestions would welcome!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259176/any-good-example-or-suggestions-to-transport-image-to-ros-in-android-jni-?/) by [Zorcs](https://answers.ros.org/users/29838/zorcs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, since I had checked the [API-for-image-sensor_msgs-transport-in-ROS-based-on-C++/Python](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/UsingCvBridgeToConvertBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImages), I have to acknowledged that there's no way to make this come true besides deal the source image with OpenCV (which called OpenCVImages in ROS) . So anyway, before you try to do this, you have to import your OpenCV-tool in your project (for me, just need [OpenCV-for-Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android/)). And, just as the API suggested, we need the [cv_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge) as a node to transform the OpenCVImages into ROS-image-messages. Fortunately, I found this [android_cv_bridge](https://github.com/talregev/android_cv_bridge) can be the best solution to solve my problem. In addition, it's really an available way to try this in JNI-way, cause it' not complicated in original-C++/Python-coding. So, guys if you're new to this, you really should take a glimpse of these good suggestions.

(PS: Still hoping for good suggestions in JNI-way.)

---

Originally posted by [Zorcs](https://answers.ros.org/users/29838/zorcs/) with karma: 16 on 2017-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0